# Does the Right function have a wildcard feature?

Tags: excel, vba, wildcard

I am trying to remove strings that end with "DL1" and "DL2" and "DL3" etc.

I came across the Right function with wildcard feature, however, it doesn't work this way.

```
sub removingDL()
dim item_description as string
dim i as integer
dim x as integer

item_description = cells(i,x)
if (Right (item_description,3) = "DL?") then   ' the issue is here 
    'remove it, let's just assume
end if 

end sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Like`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/like-operator).

```
If item_description Like "*DL?" Then...
```

If you plan to loop through a range (unclear if that's your end goal), you can [`AutoFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter) with `Criteria1:="=*DL?"` instead of looping.

Comment: Yes, you are right i am planning to loop through a range of cells. Thanks for the function recommendation. i will try it out with AutoFilter. 
Appreciate!